# How to sync changes from mongodb to elasticsearch(i.e.reflect changes in elastic when crud operation performed in mongo) using logstash

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, logstash-configuration

I just want to sync the data from mongodb to elastic using logstash. Its working good, when any new record comes in mongodb, logstash pushes into elastic. But when I update any record in mongodb then it does not change into elasticsearch. I want to make changes in the config file so that when any record updates in mongo it should reflect in elastic as well.

I have already tried by making  action => "index" as well as action =>"update" in .conf file.

Here is my mongodata.conf file

```
 input{
 mongodb{
   uri => 'mongodb://localhost:27017/DBname'

   placeholder_db_dir => '/opt/logstash'
   placeholder_db_name => 'logstash_sqlite.db'
   collection => "collectionName"
   batch_size => 500
   }
  }

filter {
 mutate {
  remove_field => [ "_id" ]
 }
}

output{
    elasticsearch{
            action => "index"
            hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
            index => "mongo_hi_log_data"
    }
    stdout{ codec => rubydebug }
  }
```

**I want to sync the data from mongodb to elastic using logstash when any record is updated or inserted in mongodb.**

Answer (score 0):

```
input {
   mongodb {
    uri => 'mongodb://mongo-db-url/your-collection'
    placeholder_db_dir => '/opt/logstash-mongodb/'
    placeholder_db_name => 'logstash_sqlite.db'
    collection => 'products'
    batch_size => 5000
  }
}

filter {
  date {
    match => [ "logdate", "ISO8601" ]
  }
  mutate {
    rename => { "[_id]" => "product_id" }
  }
}

output {
    stdout {
       codec => rubydebug
    }
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["http://es-url"]
        user => "elastic"
        password => "changeme"
        index => "your-index"
        action => "update"
        doc_as_upsert => true
        document_id => "%{product_id}"
        timeout => 30
        workers => 1
    }
}
```